# Vaadin gridpro - select all checkbox - not all checkbox are visually selected

Tags: vaadin

We are using **Vaadin gridpro v23.0.2** with Grid.SelectionMode.MULTI.

When I click on the select all check box all the record are selected (getAllSelectedItems), but the interface (view) is not updated, some rows of the list remain unselected. If i call refreshAll on the data provider than the rows are shown as selected. Is it a bug in the gridpro version ?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obOhH.png)

Kind regards,

Raphaël

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have `hashCode` and `equals` properly implemented in your data bean; see https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/data-provider/#data-binding.data-provider.item-identifiers . If you don't have them, the selection might not show up correctly.

Comment: Indeed, we had to much "equals"  in our pojo (with lombock). Thanks a lot for your answer !